# Redirect to /en for one specific url in IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have 2 urls for my website

1: domain1.com
2: domain2.com

I want to redirect "domain2.com" to "domain2.com/en" and if domain1.com is requested, I don't want it to be redirected.

been googling for hours, but cannot find a workaround.

here's what I have written so far, and returns:
domain2.com redirected you too many times.

```
<rule name="NAME" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*domain2.com*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="http://domain2.com/en/{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: You forgot the fact that for this rule even `http://domain2.com/en/` will be redirected to itself, and that's why "too many times" happens. Learn some regular expressions so that you can write patterns to exclude `/en/` from this rule.

Comment: I have added another condition -> "<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*domain2.com/en/*" negate="true" />"  and it didn't help. same error

Comment: That’s because the host header never contains /en/

Comment: I tried "query string" instead of that. It did not work either. What do you suggest?

Comment: Please always refer to Microsoft's documentation to get started, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module#defining-a-pattern

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for your time. I will post the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve the problem:

```
         <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="redirect to en" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)/en/(.*)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)/Scripts/(.*)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)/Content/(.*)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)/fonts/(.*)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)domain1.com(.*)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/en/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```